# How to customize a link with a custom module?

Tags: 8, theming, nodes, bootstrap-theme

I installed the "Private Message" module on Drupal 8.

There is a link to send a message that I want to transform into a Bootstrap button.

How to customize a link on Drupal 8 ?

Here is the HTML code of the link :

```
<div class="private_message_link_wrapper"><a href="/private_messages/9" class="private_message_link">Envoyer un message</a></div>
```

The developer of "Private Message" gave me this code, but I do not know what to do with it.

I need to create a custom module or put it in `my_theme.info.yml` ?

```
function HOOK_node_view_alter(&$build) {
  $build['private_message_link']['#title'] = t('Click me. Click me now!');
}
```

The developer of the module wrote in a comment :

```
You can implement hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter(). For example, if you are altering the link on the user profile you would implement hook_user_view_alter(). If you are altering the link on nodes, you would implement hook_node_view_alter(). If you are altering the link on comments, you would implement hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter().

In this function, you can change the output of the link by altering $build['private_message_link'] as you see fit.
```

**I created a custom module:**

`private_message_contact_button.module` :

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Hook implementations of private_message_contact_button module.
 */

use Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;

function private_message_contact_button_node_view_alter(&$build) {
  $build['private_message_link']['class'] = array('button button--primary', 'btn');
}
```

The code works, but the button is not applied.

I want to add class `btn btn-success`

And I want to add an icon make awesome in front of the text `<i class="fas fa-comment fa-lg"></i>`

I have to put what as code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS class is a sub-key of the `#attributes` of a render array like `$build`:

```
function private_message_contact_button_node_view_alter(&$build) {
  if (array_key_exists('private_message_link', $build)) {
    $build['private_message_link']['#attributes']['class'] = array('button button--primary', 'btn');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Can you tell me how to add a font-awesome icon in front of the text? See the end of my question

Comment: I guess the simpliest way would be extending/overwriting the `#title` as suggested by the module author.

Comment: yes but I do not know how to insert do awesome in markup

Comment: I updated your answer. The icon is not rendered this way

Comment: Have you tried `$build['private_message_link']['#title'] = t('<i class="fontawesome"></i> Click me. Click me now!');`

Comment: OOOPS I forgot to clean the cache. The answer works